# Field in Database Not updating while using SubmitChanges()

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to update 2 field in my database using Database Context

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ChangeDefaultUserLockingSetting(int PasswordAttempts, int DefaultLockingTime)
    {
        var defaultAccountSettings = new DefaultAccountSettingsDataContext();
        var defaultLockoutTimeSpam = defaultAccountSettings.DefaultAccountSettings.Where(u=>u.id==1).Select(u=>u.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan).First();
        var maxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = defaultAccountSettings.DefaultAccountSettings.Where(u => u.id == 1).Select(u=>u.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout).First();

        //foreach (int item in defaultLockoutTimeSpam)
        {
            defaultLockoutTimeSpam = DefaultLockingTime;
        }

        maxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = DefaultLockingTime;

        defaultAccountSettings.SubmitChanges();


        return View("Index", loadAdministrationViewModel());
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try this code.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ChangeDefaultUserLockingSetting(int PasswordAttempts, int DefaultLockingTime)
    {
        var defaultAccountSettings = new DefaultAccountSettingsDataContext();
        var defaultLockoutTimeSpam = defaultAccountSettings.DefaultAccountSettings.Where(u => u.id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        var maxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = defaultAccountSettings.DefaultAccountSettings.Where(u => u.id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

        //foreach (int item in defaultLockoutTimeSpam)
        {
            defaultLockoutTimeSpam.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = DefaultLockingTime;
        }

        maxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = DefaultLockingTime;

        defaultAccountSettings.SubmitChanges();


        return View("Index", loadAdministrationViewModel());
    }
```

Comment: You were right it was almost the solution , thanks I found the error

Answer (score 1):

I was modifying the **values** but **not** the Object

This is the proper way to do it :

```
public ActionResult ChangeDefaultUserLockingSetting(int PasswordAttempts, int DefaultLockingTime)
        {
            var defaultAccountSettings = new DefaultAccountSettingsDataContext();

            var accountSettings = defaultAccountSettings.DefaultAccountSettings.First(u => u.id == 1);

//The object should be modified and not his local value 
            accountSettings.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = DefaultLockingTime;
            accountSettings.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = PasswordAttempts;

            defaultAccountSettings.SubmitChanges();
            return View("Index", loadAdministrationViewModel());
        }
```